# Как изменить цвет точки не Enabled QRadioButton?

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, pyqt6, qradiobutton

Есть `QRadioButton`, при некоторых условиях они становятся `setEnabled(False)`, чтобы нельзя было больше в них потыкать. 
И в этом состоянии на моем мониторе отличить выбранную становится... нет, не невозможно, но требует определенных усилий.

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы `QRadioButton` были не тыкабельными, но сохраняли достаточно видимую расцветку?

Мой пример с двумя `QRadioButton`, оба не активны, один выбран, другой нет. 
У меня на системе/мониторе отличить их можно, но только сконцентрировавшись на них.

Файл `test.py` - конвертирован из `Creator`а:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(False)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 253)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 70, 89, 20))
        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 100, 89, 20))
        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
```

И файл `main.py`:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from test import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from test import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
# ?        MainWindow.setEnabled(False)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 253)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 70, 89, 20))
#        self.radioButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 100, 89, 20))
#        self.radioButton_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton_2"))
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.radioButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Включить rbs')
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.rb_enabled) 
       
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.style_sheet(False)
        
    def style_sheet(self, status):
        size = 30
        border = 2    
     
        if status:
            self.setStyleSheet('''
                #radioButton::indicator, #radioButton_2::indicator {{
                    border: {border}px solid #a35709; 
                    height: {size}px;
                    width: {size}px;
                    border-radius: {radius}px;
                    background: qradialgradient(
                        cx:.5, cy:.5, radius: {innerRatio},
                        fx:.5, fy:.5,
                        stop:0 {_color}, 
                        stop:0.45 {_color},
                        stop:0.5 transparent,
                        stop:1 transparent
                    );
                }}              
                #radioButton::indicator:checked, #radioButton_2::indicator:checked {{
                    background: qradialgradient(
                        cx:.5, cy:.5, radius: {innerRatio},
                        fx:.5, fy:.5,
                        stop:0 {checkColor}, 
                        stop:0.45 {checkColor},
                        stop:0.5 transparent,
                        stop:1 transparent
                        );
                }}         
            '''.format(
                size=size - border * 2,                     
                border=border, 
                radius=size // 2, 
                innerRatio=1 - (border * 2 + 1) / size, 
                _color='rgba(255, 0, 0, 255)',
                checkColor='rgba(0, 100, 0, 200)',
            ))         
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet('''
                #radioButton::indicator, #radioButton_2::indicator {{
                    border: {border}px solid #a35709; 
                    height: {size}px;
                    width: {size}px;
                    border-radius: {radius}px;
                    background: qradialgradient(
                        cx:.5, cy:.5, radius: {innerRatio},
                        fx:.5, fy:.5,
                        stop:0 {_color}, 
                        stop:0.45 {_color},
                        stop:0.5 transparent,
                        stop:1 transparent
                    );
                }}              
                #radioButton::indicator:checked, #radioButton_2::indicator:checked {{
                    
                    background: qradialgradient(
                        cx:.5, cy:.5, radius: {innerRatio},
                        fx:.5, fy:.5,
                        stop:0 {checkColor}, 
                        stop:0.45 {checkColor},
                        stop:0.5 transparent,
                        stop:1 transparent
                        );
                }}         
            '''.format(
                size=size - border * 2,                     
                border=border, 
                radius=size // 2, 
                innerRatio=1 - (border * 2 + 1) / size, 
                _color='rgba(255, 0, 0, 99)',
                checkColor='rgba(0, 100, 0, 99)',
            ))         


    def rb_enabled(self, status):
        if status:
            self.radioButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.radioButton_2.setEnabled(True)
            self.style_sheet(True)
            self.pushButton.setText('Отключить rbs')
        else:
            self.radioButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.radioButton_2.setEnabled(False) 
            self.style_sheet(False)
            self.pushButton.setText('Включить rbs')
            
        
QSS = '''
#centralwidget {background-color: #B0E0E6;}
QRadioButton {font: 15pt "ariel" bold;}
QPushButton {
    border: none;
    background-color: #00008B;
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;  
    color: #fff;    
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    color: #000; 
    font: 10pt "ariel" bold;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: PS =_= Акелла промахнулся, хотел вырубить второй radio, а вырубил весь mainwindow xD

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 пожалуйста